# How to maintain sorting order of entities

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an entity `AllComponentEntity` which has properties other entities like `Allergy`, `VitalList`, etc. Each of these entities has a field named `SortngOrder` of type `int`. If `Allergy` has `SortingOrder == 1` then I will treat it first and so on.

How can I sort all entites in my `AllComponentEntity` by their `SortingOrder` field so that I can treat them accordingly?

Following is my AllCompnentEntity

```
   public AllergyComponentEntity Allergy { get; set; }
   public List<VitalComponentEntity> VitalList { get; set; }
```

Following is Allergy component Entity

```
   public string AllergyName{ get; set; }
   public int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

Following is VitalComponentEntity component Entity

```
   public bool VitalTemp{  get;set;}
   public bool VitalResp {  get; set; }
   public bool VitalPulse{get;set;}
   public int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you add some code snippets so we'll know how to give you a specific answer?

Comment: give us your code to help you

Comment: A picture of this part of your EF model would be helpful.

Comment: Is `AllComponentEntity` a single object (because it has _properties_) or a collection of objects? Also Entity sounds as if it is `Linq-To-Entities` but you havent mentioned that.

Comment: I have pasted code here. I have now it will give you a clear idea about this. I want entities in AllComponentEntity to be sorted by SordingOrder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to have all your entities (like Allergy, VitalList etc.)  implement an interface with the 
SortingOrder like so:

```
interface ISortable
{
    int SortingOrder { get; }
}
```

And then have AllComponentEntity create a method like the following:

```
public IEnumerable<ISortable> GetProperties()
{
    yield return Allergy;
    foreach(var vce in VitalList)
        yield return vce;
}
```

You will then be able to sort using

```
AllComponentEntity.GetProperties().OrderBy(x=>x.SortOrder);
```

To enumerate all properties using the AllComponentEntity, then you must have it implement the IEnumerable interface. This will allow you to iterate usint the AllComponentEntity directly.

The full source code is shown below:

```
interface ISortable
{
    int SordOrder { get; }
}

class AllergyComponentEntity : ISortable
{
    public string AllergyName { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

class VitalComponentEntity : ISortable
{
    public bool VitalTemp { get; set; }
    public bool VitalResp { get; set; }
    public bool VitalPulse { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

class AllComponentEntity : IEnumerable<ISortable>
{
    public AllergyComponentEntity Allergy { get; set; }
    public List<VitalComponentEntity> VitalList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ISortable> GetProperties()
    {
        yield return Allergy;
        foreach (var vce in VitalList)
            yield return vce;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ISortable> GetSorted()
    {
        return GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.SordOrder);
    }

    public IEnumerator<ISortable> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetSorted().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetSorted().GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And you call into the AllComponentEntity like below:

```
    AllComponentEntity ace = new AllComponentEntity();

    foreach (ISortable sortable in ace)
        DoSomething(ace);
```

Comment: SKleanthous ! You solution is really awesome. Can't I get my sorted AllComponentEntity back instead of sorted entites ?

Comment: If you want to do that, I think it is best that you simply make your AllComponentEntity derive from IEnumerable and implement it so as to return an IEnumerator that will give you all the values in sorted order. It is not very difficult. Give me 10 minutes and I will update the answer to include that as an example.